# Should we add "d", "f", etc. at the end of double, float values in Java?

Tags: java, double

I am generally confused when defining double and float variables and as far as I know, it is good practice to add "d", "f", etc. at the end of double, float values. However, as the IDE does not warn me, generally I omit them and think it would also be ok and no need to add these letters. Regarding to these variables:

**1.** Is there any letter except from "d" and "f" added to the variable definitions (double, float) in Java?

**2.** Why do we add these letters at the end of float and double variable definitions? And should we use or not?

**3.** When defining these variables (except from List, Map, etc.) as shown below, should I prefer primitive or wrapper class version of them?

I simply define a double like:

```
double quantityAmount = 200d;

// or

double quantityAmount = 200;
```

Could you please clarify me about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. for float(F or f) and double(D or d) for more check (Default Values):https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html. The floating point types (float and double) can also be expressed using E or e (for scientific notation), F or f (32-bit float literal) and D or d (64-bit double literal; this is the default and by convention is omitted).
2. A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally end with the letter D or d.
3. that depends on you. :)

Comment: Thanks amigo, voted up ;) What about the other suffices used for variable definitions besides f, d, ..?

Comment: @Jonathan There is also `L` and `l` for `long` type literals. BTW always prefer `L` over `l` since lower-case can look like `1` (for comparison `1` vs `l`) in some fonts which can be confusing.

Comment: @Jonathan L is preferred for long (as answered by - Pshemo). These literals are just for the compiler to correctly allocated memory to the right datatype. Like in python this is done automatically by the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes. Read the official language documentation for a full list! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10
2. Why: to denote the type when you need to specify the type; for example, say you have an overloaded function that has one implementation for int, and one for double; if you pass `300`, it will call the `int` version, if you pass `300d`, it will call the double version.
3. Preference is a personal thing, I can't tell you what you like. Functionally, both are constant initializations with a trivial data type and do (bytecode-bitwise!) exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanations. Regarding to your answers, could you clarify me a little bit more for the following points?

Comment: **#1.** Is there any difference between capital and small letters of the suffix (d / D)?

Comment: **#2.** Documentation is a little bit confused, what is the other suffices used like f, d ? Could you pls give some other examples?

Comment: #2 How is the documentation confused? It's quite clear! How about you search for "suffix" on that page!